# Application.Current.Resources empty in ScheduledTaskAgent?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I want to regenerate tiles based on external changes in my ScheduledTaskAgent.

I am calling the same code  that I use in my app.  This code makes use of some resources defined in Application.Current.Resources, and this collection is empty when used from the ScheduledTaskAgent.

Does anyone know of a way to force this collection to be loaded, or am I going to have to manually create my brushes, etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Background agents run in the background (hence the name) and do not fully load your application (from a UI perspective at least), hence the empty Resources collection.

Given the background nature of these tasks, it would seem strange that you would need access to these resources, though. Perhaps if you explain your scenario a little further so we can provide more help.

Comment: I'm re-using brushes to regenerate part of the tile's image, dynamically, building a grid, with various content, including an ImageBrush that is defined in the Resources collection.  If necessary I can generate all the UI elements in code, but it would be a pain.

Comment: XamlReader.Load might work if I hard-coded the App.xaml as a string :-)

Comment: It sounds like you need to write the bits you need into isolated storage so you can access it from there.

Comment: As well as the ImageBrushes, I have a fairly complex TextBlock style which  guess I'll have to hard-code into C#.  It would be nice to be able to load the application's resources on demand.